# Can't get Ruby Whenever working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

I'm having some trouble getting `whenever` to work in my local dev environment. I'm using `mac OS 10.12`, `ruby 2.4`, `rails 5.1` and `whenever 0.10.0`.

I have my `schedule.rb` file setup as:

```
set :environment, "development"
set :job_template, "TZ=\"America/Los_Angeles\" bash -l -c ':job'"
set :output, Whenever.path + "/log/cron.log"

every 5.minutes do
  runner "Test.new.run"
  command "/bin/echo 'Is this working?'"
end
```

`crontab -l` outputs the following:

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/me/apps/Test/config/schedule.rb at: 2018-05-25 12:59:14 -0700
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * TZ="America/Los_Angeles" bash -l -c 'cd /Users/me/apps/Test && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e development '\''Test.new.run'\'' >> /Users/me/apps/Test/log/cron.log 2>&1'

0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * TZ="America/Los_Angeles" bash -l -c '/bin/echo '\''Is this working?'\'' >> /Users/me/apps/Test/log/cron.log 2>&1'


# End Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/me/apps/Test/config/schedule.rb at: 2018-05-25 12:59:14 -0700
```

and I'm receiving the following when I run the `mail` command in terminal:

```
  Message 1:
From me@box.local  Fri May 25 13:00:01 2018
X-Original-To: me
Delivered-To: me@box.local
From: me@box.local (Cron Daemon)
To: me@box.local
Subject: Cron <me@box> TZ="America/Los_Angeles" bash -l -c '/bin/echo '\''Is this working?'\'' >> /Users/me/apps/Test/log/cron.log 2>&1'
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=me>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=me>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/me>
Date: Fri, 25 May 2018 13:00:00 -0700 (PDT)
```

However, I'm not seeing anything output to `cron.log` nor does the DB reflect any activity from `Test.new.run`

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: What does `Test.new.run` do? Could it be that it has nothing to tell you?

Comment: It sends an email and saves a record to the DB. I've tested it running in `console` and it works properly.

Comment: Rails console has special setup to duplicate database queries to your terminal session as well as your ${RAILS_ENV}.log file. Try checking your application log for the queries started from cron job.

Comment: Shouldn't i at least be seeing the echo in the `cron.log` file?

Comment: Yes, you're right. You should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may have had to do with `rvm` and the `.rvmrc` file I had set up which loaded the correct `rvm` settings when I `cd` into the directory.

In attempting to ensure that the command was working opened a new terminal window and ran: `bash -l -c 'cd /Users/me/apps/Test && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e development '\''Test.new.run'\'' >> /Users/me/apps/Test/log/cron.log 2>&1'`

The first thing that came up was the standard 1 off rvm message:

```
You are using '.rvmrc', it requires trusting, it is slower and it is not compatible with other ruby managers,
you can switch to '.ruby-version' using 'rvm rvmrc to ruby-version'
or ignore this warning with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/me/apps/Test/.rvmrc',
'.rvmrc' will continue to be the default project file in RVM 1 and RVM 2,
to ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore all.rvmrcs'.

********************************************************************************
* NOTICE                                                                       *
********************************************************************************
* RVM has encountered a new or modified .rvmrc file in the current directory,  *
* this is a shell script and therefore may contain any shell commands.         *
*                                                                              *
* Examine the contents of this file carefully to be sure the contents are      *
* safe before trusting it!                                                     *
* Do you wish to trust                                                         *
* '/Users/me/apps/Test/.rvmrc'?                                                *
* Choose v[iew] below to view the contents                                     *
********************************************************************************
y[es], n[o], v[iew], c[ancel]>
```

Once I typed `y` and hit enter, the cron jobs are now executing properly.

Unfortunately, I'm still not seeing anything in my `cron.log` file.